# Yii, querying gives array to string error

Tags: php, yii

```
$paymentIDs = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT payment_id FROM client_package WHERE package_id = :pid AND payment_id IS NOT NULL')->bindValue(':pid', $pid)->queryAll();

$total = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT count(*) FROM payment WHERE id IN ('.implode(",", $paymentIDs).') AND date BETWEEN \':mS\' AND \':mE\'')->bindValue(':mS', $monthStart)->bindValue(':mE', $monthEnd)->queryScalar();
```

The above is my code for a query. As you can see, I queried for `payment_id`(s) according to a certain criteria. And I now have a set of numbers.

When I execute the second query, it fails, throwing me an error

> Array to String conversion

I have also tried this:

```
$total = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT count(*) FROM payment WHERE id IN ('.implode(",", $paymentIDs['payment_id']).') AND date BETWEEN \':mS\' AND \':mE\'')->bindValue(':mS', $monthStart)->bindValue(':mE', $monthEnd)->queryScalar();
```

Now, this gives me an error saying:

> Undefined index: payment_id

Can someone please point out my mistake? Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't put `\'` around parameters. Also what values does parameters contains? `var_dump($pid, $monthStart, $monthEnd, $paymentIDs);`. Also consider using chinned version of Query Builder `...->select()->where()...` or CActiveRecord and CDbCriteria

Comment: I have tested, they do return a valid/desired result. Basically the parameters are all working fine. And, why not put `\'` around the date? isn't it suppose to be like `BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-06-01'`? what `$monthStart` and `$monthEnd` give are: 2015-05-01 and 2015-06-01, yes, without quotes.

Comment: Because Yii adds `'` automatically to variables. If every parameter is of type string, than you have error somewhere else, try to figure out in what file and line error is thrown. (In error page `$line` and `$file`)

Comment: I don't think you understand my question correctly. What I have tested again is, in the 2nd query, in the implode, I took whatever there is in `$paymentIDs` (after print_r), I inserted the numbers into the implode, it's working fine, for example, `... IN (2,7,8,13,14,17)..` this would work fine. BUT not if I were to do `... IN(implode(",", $paymentIDs))...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the first query, `$paymentIDs`, is an array of arrays (or plain objects, I'm not sure). You can try inspecting it in your IDE or simply use `var_dump` to see its structure. You can use the [`listData` method of the CHtml class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) to get closer to what you want, like this:

```
$ids = CHtml::listData($paymentIDs, 'payment_id', 'payment_id');
```

That will flatten your array to an array of strings. Then...

```
implode(",", $ids)
```

...will give you the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using single Query like this :

```
 $total = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT count(*) FROM payment WHERE id IN (SELECT payment_id FROM client_package WHERE package_id = :pid AND payment_id IS NOT NULL) AND date BETWEEN \':mS\' AND \':mE\'')->bindValue(':pid', $pid)->bindValue(':mS', $monthStart)->bindValue(':mE', $monthEnd)->queryScalar();
```

Thanks You :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your first query returns array of objects (not array of `payment_id`s).
   To get array of values of some column you can use `->queryColumn()`.
   So the first query must be:

`$paymentIDs = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT payment_id FROM client_package WHERE package_id = :pid AND payment_id IS NOT NULL')->bindValue(':pid', $pid)->queryColumn()`

If variables `$monthStart` and `$monthEnd` have a `string` type (or a type that can be converted to `string`), the code must work fine.

2. In second query you can use `bindValues` instead of double `bindValue`.